# Installing Xcode 4.1 and Xcode 3.X on Mac OS X Lion

Tags: macos, install, xcode

I need to install both Xcode 4.1 and Xcode 3.X on Lion.
After installing Xcode 4.1, when I tried to install Xcode 3.X in `~/Developer`, I find that I can't install Xcode Toolset with the installer.

Does this mean one can't install Xcode 3.X on Lion? Is there a way to install Xcode Toolset?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The installer for Xcode 3.x fails when you try to run the installer against Lion.

Xcode 4.0 also does not work under Lion, and purposely refuses to start.

Some Developer applications (like Dashcode) do start but more often than not just crash.

If you really depend on Xcode 3 your best bet is to keep Snow Leopard on a second partition alongside Lion and dual boot when needed. AFAIK you can nonetheless target previous Mac OS X and iOS versions to some extend in Xcode 4.1.

You can try installing it on Snow Leopard and then upgrading to Lion - that's the best chance, but it might be easier to keep an external disk bootable with Snow Leopard and Xcode 3.x just in case you run into any glitches down the road.

Comment: Yup the installer for XCode 3 will refuse to run on Lion so the only way you could even have it on Lion is if you installed it on SL and upgraded to Lion. Even so when you install XCode 4 the newer unix command line tools will overwrite the XCode 3. Lastly, I personally got direct confirmation from Apple that XCode 3 is only officially supported on SL.

Answer (score 1):

[This site](http://anatomicwax.tumblr.com/post/8064949186/installing-xcode-3-2-6-on-lion-redux) has a trick to install Xcode 3.2.6 on Lion at your own risk.